# how to improve my code iteration through two different data frame with 100K rows to decrease processing speed in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, bigdata

Could you please take a look at my code and give me some advice how I might improve my code so it takes less time to process? Main purpose is to look at each row (ID) at test table and find same ID at list table, if it's match then look at time difference between the two identical ID and label them as if it takes less than 1 hours (3600s) or not. 
Thanks in advance

test.csv  has two col (ID, time) and 100K rows 
   list.csv  has tow col (ID, time) and 40k rows

sample data:
ID               Time
83d-36615fa05fb0 2019-12-11 10:41:48

```
a = -1
for row_index,row in test.iterrows():
   a = a + 1

   for row_index2,row2 in list.iterrows():

       if row['ID'] == row2['ID']:
           time_difference = row['Time'] - row2['Time']
           time_difference = time_difference.total_seconds() 

           if time_difference < 3601 and time_difference > 0:
               test.loc[a, 'result'] = "short waiting time"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't break out of the inner loop when you set test.loc[a, 'result'] = "short waiting time"?

Comment: On the inner loop couldn't you filter rows in 'list' whose row ID is row['ID'] by [Selecting rows in pandas DataFrame based on conditions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selecting-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-conditions/)

Comment: Thanks, I added the break as you suggested but don't know what do you mean exactly about filtering rows. could you share the code base on what you suggested?

Comment: 'list' is a bad name for Dataframe.  But meant inner_rows = list['ID'] == row['[ID'].  Then have row_index2, row2 in inner_rows.iterrows().  This way Pandas equally find the rows with vaue row['ID'] using [row filtering based upon value](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_selecting_rows_on_conditions/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ot belonga to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DarryIG thanks for help, I have changed variables name before post it and simplify the problem.

Comment: @ari--was my answer of any help?

Comment: @DarryIG yeah, thanks  for help, because I'm new user it doesn't show the upvote publicly.

Answer (score 0):

You should not loop through the rows of your data frames at all. 
Instead combine your test and list data frames using
The merge or join methods from you data frame using ‘ID’ as the ‘on’ join key. 
You the have the data in one big table and you create a new column where you subtract Time.x from the first table from Time.y in the second table. 
E.g call the new column ‘timediff ’. 
You then filter the result data frame by this timediff column for timediff < 3601.

suppose dataframes are named testdf and listdf.

```
joindf = testdf.merge(listdf, on='ID')
joindf['timediff'] = joindf['Time_x'] - joindf['Time_y']
joindf.loc[timediff < 3601, 'result'] = 'short waiting time'
```

Answer (score 0):

The code could be converted to the following.

```
def find_match(id_val, time_val, df):
    " This uses your algorithm for generating a string based upon time difference "
    # Find rows with matching ID in Dataframe df 
    #   (this will be list_ref in our usage)
    matches = df[df['ID'] == id_val]

    if not matches.empty:
        # Use iterrows on matched rows
        # This replaced your inner loop but only apply to rows with the same ID
        for row_index2, row2 in matches.iterrows():
            time_difference = time_val - row2['Time']
            time_difference = time_difference.total_seconds()
            if 0 < time_difference < 3601:
                return "short waiting time"  # Exit since found a time in window

    return ""  # Didn't find a time in our window

# Test
#     test - your test Dataframe
#     list_ref - (your list DataFrame, but using list_ref since list is a bad 
#                name for a Python variable)


# Create result using Apply
# More info on Apply available https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

test['result'] = test.apply(lambda row: find_match (row['ID'], row['Time'], list_ref), axis = 1)
```